# Inorder successor in a binary search tree

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

This is a common algorithm question. I'm trying to find the inorder successor in a binary search tree. Here's my code

```
def inorderSuccessor(self, root, p):
        """
        :type root: TreeNode
        :type p: TreeNode
        :rtype: TreeNode
        """
        # if Node has a right child, go all the way down
        if p.right:
            curr = p
            while curr.left:
                curr = curr.left
            return curr
        # first ancestor whose left child the node is
        ans = None
        curr = root
        while curr is not p:
            if curr.val < p.val:
                curr = curr.right
            else:
                ans = curr
                curr = curr.left
        return ans
```

The problem is that this doesn't work when p is the highest node in the tree. I've been scratching my head over how to get this edge case going.

Comment: Are you trying to implement in-order tree traversal?

Comment: Nope in-order traversal has O(n) complexity. I'm trying to find the in-order successor at O(log n) complexity, assuming the tree is balanced.

Comment: What is your input? What is your actual/expected output? Adding these help.

Comment: after `if p.right` you set `curr = p` but you really want `curr = p.right`.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a method within your BST Class as below

```
def InOrderSucc(self,childNode):
    if(self.search(childNode)):
        if not (self.data == childNode):
            return(self.right.InOrderSucc(childNode))
        else:
            if(self.right):
                return(self.right.data)
            else:
                return None
    else:
        return False
```

where childNode is the Node you are requesting to find its InOrder Successor, Noting that the InOrder Successor will always be the right Child.